# how to return array as stream in flutter firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to return a post array from firestore as a stream in flutter.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('groups')
        .doc(groupId)
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (_, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final docs = snapshot.data!.docs;

        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: querySnapshot.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: ((context, i) {
              final docdata = docs[i].data();
              return ListTile();
            }));
      } else {
        return Text('wait');
      }
      ;
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: Don't build the stream as the stream: parameter in StreamBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg.

Comment: What is the error you facing?

Comment: @user18309290 THIS IS THE ERROR==>The argument type 'Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?'.

Answer (score 0):

Query returns a single document i.e. a stream with [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/snapshots.html) type instead of `QuerySnapshot`.

```
  StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('groups')
        .doc(groupId)
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (_, snapshot) {
...
    },
  ),
```